# Updating a CTE table fail cause of derived or constant field

Tags: t-sql

I'm using MS-SQL 2012

```
WITH C1
(
   SELECT ID, 0 as Match, Field2, Count(*)
   FROM TableX
   GROUP BY ID, Fields2
)

UPDATE C1 SET Match = 1 
WHERE ID = (SELECT MATCHING_ID FROM AnotherTable WHERE ID = C1.ID)
```

This TSQL statement gives me the following error:

> > Update or insert of view or function 'C1' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Ideally I would like to create a "fake field" named Match and set its default value to 0. Then with the update I would like to Update ONLY the records that have an existing entry on the "AnotherTable".

Any thoughts what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a Left Outer Join like

```
   SELECT x.ID, ISNULL(a.Matching_ID, 0) as Match, x.Field2, Count(*)
   FROM TableX x
         LEFT OUTER JOIN AnotherTable a on x.ID = a.ID
   GROUP BY x.ID, ISNULL(a.Matching_ID, 0), x.Fields2
```

without the need of a C1

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, the problem is that you are trying to update the CTE table. If you update the table directly you should be fine.

Does this modified version help?

```
SELECT t.ID
, CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT MATCHING_ID FROM AnotherTable WHERE ID = t.ID)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
,t.Field2
,Count(*)
FROM TableX t
GROUP BY ID, Fields2
```

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll check the impact of running a LEFT OUTER vs a CASE statement. Thanks again.